# How to create a scala object in clojure

Tags: scala, clojure, apache-kafka

I'm trying to create a scala object, `kafka.utils.ZKStringSerializer` in clojure. (It's in `org.apache.kafka/kafka_2.10 "0.8.0"`)

Since I know little about scala, I don't know how to call its constructor. I tried like this:

```
(import 'kafka.utils.ZKStringSerializer)
(ZKStringSerializer.)                      
; or (new ZKStringSerializer)
```

And got an error: `CompilerException java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No matching ctor found for class kafka.utils.ZKStringSerializer`

I tried using `(clojure.reflect/reflect ZKStringSerializer)` to see its methods but there are only some static methods.  And `(class ZKStringSerializer)` tells me it is a class, not an instance I want.

The object is implemented like this:

```
object ZKStringSerializer extends ZkSerializer {

  @throws(classOf[ZkMarshallingError])
  def serialize(data : Object) : Array[Byte] = data.asInstanceOf[String].getBytes("UTF-8")

  @throws(classOf[ZkMarshallingError])
  def deserialize(bytes : Array[Byte]) : Object = {
    if (bytes == null)
      null
    else
      new String(bytes, "UTF-8")
  }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

All scala objects are singletons in terms of `java`. There is no public constructor. You should use static field `MODULE$` to get an instance of singleton.

I don't know `clojure`, but according to [this page](http://clojure.org/java_interop#Java%20Interop-Classname/staticField) it looks like you should use this:

```
ZKStringSerializer$/MODULE$
```

Note also that the actual type name of object contains `$` as last character.

Comment: It works! Thanks a lot! I didn't know the `$` notation before.

Comment: @halfelf: take a look at companion object: `class Test; object Test`. An instance of singleton should have a class, but class name `Test` is already in use. Manual usage of `$` is deprecated in scala: all synthetic term names contains `$`.

Comment: @halfelf: actually not all synthetic term names contains `$`, only methods you should not use manually.

Comment: hmm.. looks like [that page](http://clojure.org/java_interop#Java%20Interop-Classname/staticField) no longer references `MODULE$`.

fwiw, i'm wondering how to access a scala object from clojure.

Comment: @arigold that page describes accessing java static fields. Scala creates java static field `MODULE$` for singleton objects.

Comment: ah i see, thanks.. it was an indirect reference.