# Zookeeper property still a requirement in the Kafka consumer?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I was referring to a post here:
[Connecting to Zookeeper in a Apache Kafka Multi Node cluster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38583608/connecting-to-zookeeper-in-a-apache-kafka-multi-node-cluster)

Its mentioned here that from kafka V9 version, Producer and Consumer does not have to use the zookeeper.connect property and just the bootstrap.servers is enough to producer/consume data.

My POM.xml looks like this in the consumer side:

```
<properties>
    <java.version>1.7</java.version>
    <kafka.version>0.9.0.1-cp1</kafka.version>
    <kafka.scala.version>2.11</kafka.scala.version>
    <confluent.version>2.0.1</confluent.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>


<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
<artifactId>kafka_2.10</artifactId>
<version>0.10.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I run into the following issue in the consumer side, without zookeeper.connect property. Does anyone has the consumer part working without the zookeeper connect property ?

```
[WARNING] 
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run(ExecJavaMojo.java:297)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Missing required property 'zookeeper.connect'
at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:233)
at kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties.getString(VerifiableProperties.scala:177)
at kafka.utils.ZKConfig.<init>(ZkUtils.scala:902)
at kafka.consumer.ConsumerConfig.<init>(ConsumerConfig.scala:101)
at kafka.consumer.ConsumerConfig.<init>(ConsumerConfig.scala:105)
at io.confluent.examples.consumer.ConsumerGroup.<init>(ConsumerGroup.java:30)
at io.confluent.examples.consumer.ConsumerGroup.main(ConsumerGroup.java:113)
... 6 more
```

Answer (score 2):

Only the new consumer works without connecting to Zookeeper and that is available in the kafka-clients artifact. You have to add the dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
    <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
    <version>0.10.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

and use the implementation from the `org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.` package.

Comment: Also the KafkaProducer in the package `org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer` don't communicate with the zookeeper.